# react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.createRoo

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, relay

When using the experimental version of react-dom, react-relay and react I got errors like

```
react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.createRoo
```

```
TypeError: useTransition is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fixed by using react latest 18 +

```
yarn add react@latest
```

or

```
npm install react@latest
```

createRoot and useTransition

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootEl).render(<App />)
```